# How to Convert CloudFlare Rules to HAPROXY?

Tags: configuration, haproxy, cloudflare, rules

I am trying to convert the following rule to HAPROXY rule but it is not working for some reason. maybe somebody can help.

CF Rule

```
(http.request.method eq "GET" and http.request.uri.query eq "" and http.request.version eq "HTTP/1.1" and any(len(http.request.headers.values[*])[*] gt 60) )
```

Cloudflare Firewall Rules Page:
(https://developers.cloudflare.com/firewall/cf-firewall-language/fields#dynamic-fields
"Documentation")

Tried something simple without http version and query string, but still not working.

HAPROXY:

```
 acl test1 hdr_cnt() gt 60
 http-request deny  if METH_GET test1
```

also tried with same method below and it didn’t work

req.fhdr_cnt

Comment: Can you add details about the error / message you are receiving? If I had to guess, it seems like the CF firewall rule is looking for *any individual* header value to be over 60 characters, whereas your HA Proxy rule is looking for more than 60 headers *in total*?

Comment: I am not receiving errors, but I did test HAProxy & Cloudflare rules. CF Rules works pretty good but HAProxy rules doesn't because I couldn't accomplish same goal. I want to write same rules with HAProxy in order to get it work. Yep CF is looking for any individual header value to be over 60 characters, is there any way to write rule with HaProxy ? Thanks

Comment: Not able to test it but seems like `hdr_len` may be what you are looking for?

Comment: Tried to match hdr_len  with regex but still same problem, and it is not matching properly